# How to change featurelayer symbol in ArcGIS silverlight API?

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-silverlight-api

I created a webgis using ArcGIS silverlight API . my map contains network ( roads) and some points. The user want to change the network color. Is there any solution to change the featurelayer symbol ?